# Can't find persistence.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

I try to use jpa with spring-orm and hibernate.

I have mysql db with TRADES table. I try to work with this table using jpa.
I try to test EntityManager creation using persistence.xml but I get an exception that "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named [persistence-unit-name from persistence.xml]"
As I watched in another such questions, it's mean for my situation that persistence.xml file is not found.

When I try to test this configuration I get an exception that persistence.xml wasn't find, as I think.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named trade-mysql-pu
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at com.madhusudhan.jsd.jpa.EntityManagerTest.init(EntityManagerTest.java:16)
    at com.madhusudhan.jsd.jpa.EntityManagerTest.main(EntityManagerTest.java:29)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Could you help me?
Thanks.

Table:

```
create table TRADES (ID int NOT NULL, 
    ACCOUNT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    SECURITY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    QUANTITY INT NOT NULL, 
    STATUS VARCHAR(10), 
    DIRECTION VARCHAR(10)
);
```

entity class for this table:

```
package com.madhusudhan.jsd.domain.jpa;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="trades")
public class Trade {

    private int id;
    private String direction;
    private String account;
    private String security;
    private String status;
    private int quantity;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }
    public void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    @Column
    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(String account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Column
    public String getSecurity() {
        return security;
    }
    public void setSecurity(String security) {
        this.security = security;
    }

    @Column
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Trade [id=" + id + ", direction=" + direction + ", account="
                + account + ", security=" + security + ", status=" + status
                + "]";
    }

}
```

And persistence.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="trade-mysql-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter</provider>
        <class>com.madhusudhan.jsd.domain.jpa.Trade</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JSDATA"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="prospring4"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="prospring4"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the test class:

```
package com.madhusudhan.jsd.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.madhusudhan.jsd.domain.jpa.Trade;

public class EntityManagerTest {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private void init() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("trade-mysql-pu");
        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void persistTrade(Trade t) {
        entityManager.persist(t);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerTest test = new EntityManagerTest();
        test.init();
    }
}
```

dependencies from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.18'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.0.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.0.Final'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.7'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.14'
}
```

Comment: What is your layout of build? Where is persistence.xml?

Comment: @LeosLiterak persistence.xml is in src/main/resources/META-INF, src/main/resources/ is in build path without any exclusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things you can try:

1. Check that your src/main/resources folder is in your classpath. In Eclipse, it means right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path and make sure that src/main/resources is specified under Source tab. If it is not there, click Add Folder to add resources folder.
2. If the above does not work, try to move your persistence.xml to src/main/java/META-INF folder.
3. Change to provider in persistence.xml to

   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Comment: Hello, Tony. Thanks for the respone. But I tried move the folder to src/main/java and there's the same result. Also I checked that in Eclipse /java and /resources are in build path without any excluded files.

Comment: Is persistence.xml indeed copied to target WEB-INF/classes folder? Alo try my third suggestion above.

Comment: thanks. It's standalone app and it shouldn't have WEB-INF as I think.

Comment: Thanks for you help! It's standalone app and it shouldn't have WEB-INF as I think. The persistence.xml file was found when it was used HibernatePersistence class as a provider instead of HibernateJpaVendorAdapter. Now I've got a message about inconsistence "detached entity passed to persist", will try to figure out why this happened.